# Database access from UWP app in HTML5/JS

Tags: javascript, html, win-universal-app, uwp

What is the best way to use a database (be it Redis, SQLite, WebSQL or just about anything actually) from a UWP app *being developed in HTML5/Javascript*? For a C# or VB.NET app I guess it would be quite easy, since you can just use stuff like [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/826602/Using-SQLite-as-local-database-with-Universal-Apps). But how would I do that for a JS-based app?

I guess one option would be to do a wrapper C# project and use that as a data layer (since I believe my JS/HTML project can invoke methods in my other projects in the solution). Is that the best/easiest way or are there any other really good options that I'm missing somehow? It feels a bit clumsy, since I would prefer a solution with 100% Javascript in this case.

Answer (score 1):

You could use IndexedDB in UWP javascript apps.

You can easily find samples online ([here](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/IndexedDB-sample-eb1e95af) for example) and relevant MSDN documentation is [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj553412.aspx).

Comment: Thanks! Are there any other good options that you know of? Are there any disk space/quota limitations in place that could cause issues?

Comment: I'm not sure if there is any native java script implementations of SQLite. But you can use it via a component. Here is a sample for sqlite: https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Universal-JavaScript-5728abdb/